# Multi language in single domain in subdirectory

Tags: php, nginx, magento2

I want to achieve this by subdirectory:

Website ABC

```
Domain | Store View Code

abc.com/en -> my_en
abc.com/ms -> my_ms
abc.com/zh -> my_zh
abc.hk/en  -> hk_en
abc.hk/zh  -> hk_zh
```

I have setup my nginx map to read it works as intended but I'm receiving 404 error when trying to access the site.

Here is my nginx setup:

```
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
        default my_en;
        ~^/zh my_zh;
        ~^/ms my_ms;
}

map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_TYPE {
    default   store;
    ~^/zh     store;
    ~^/ms     store;
}

upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server  unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}

server {
     listen 80;
     server_name abc.com;
     set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html;
     include /var/www/html/nginx.conf.sample;
}
```

The store changed successfully, but it is showing me 404 error. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this...
[image]